# How to create an edgelist from a dataframe (expand, group_by?)

Tags: r, networking, igraph, expand

I have a dataframe in R similar to the following:

```
INSTITUTION  GROUP
University1  Group1
University1  Group1
University3  Group2
University4  Group2
University1  Group2
University3  Group3
```

My intent is to create an edgelist to create a network in igraph of all the possible connections between institutions within their respective groups. The idea is that relationships wouldn't repeat. It would look something like this (I assume):

```
EDGE1        EDGE2       
University1  University1 # for group 1
University3  University4 # for group 2
University3  University1 # for group 2
University4  University1 # for group 2
 
# and I assume that group 3 would not have an edge represented because it is alone.
```

I have been trying to figure out how to do this with `igraph` or with `tidyverse` and I am not sure how to go about it, as I always end up with repeated pairs or elements like `Univerisity3` from `group3` that I don't need.

## Bonus question!

Once I have my edgelist set up, how can I limit the number edges shown in the network graph? For example, I would like to eliminate all edges that appear less than 10 times. The actual dataset is quite large and has many institutions.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Isn't University 1 on its own too? It's only connected by itself?

Comment: If that doesn't matter, then maybe `delete_vertices(connect(g, order=2), dat$GROUP)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first construct a bipartite graph, then do a so-called [bipartite projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_network_projection).

```
library(igraph)

df <- read.table(header=T,text=
"INSTITUTION  GROUP
University1  Group1
University1  Group1
University3  Group2
University4  Group2
University1  Group2
University3  Group3")

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)

V(g)$type <- V(g)$name %in% df[,1]
```

igraph uses the `type` vertex attribute to encode which vertex belongs to which partition within the bipartite graph.

Now we can do the projection:

```
> bipartite_projection(g)
$proj1
IGRAPH 98f44c3 UNW- 3 2 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges from 98f44c3 (vertex names):
[1] Group1--Group2 Group2--Group3

$proj2
IGRAPH ac701ec UNW- 3 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges from ac701ec (vertex names):
[1] University1--University3 University1--University4
[3] University3--University4
```

This gives us the university-university, as well as the group-group relationships in two result graphs.

To get only the university-university relations, use

```
bipartite_projection(g, which="true")
```

This will give you the graph which has the vertices marked with `TRUE` in the `type` attribute. In our case that's the universities.

See here for details: https://igraph.org/r/html/latest/bipartite_projection.html

Answer (score 3):

I really love a base R solution, so that's what you'll get from me. It's a bit hacky and ad hoc but it seems to get the job done pretty quickly.

```
out <- do.call("rbind", lapply(split(data, data$GROUP), function(d) {
   if (nrow(d) > 1) unique(do.call("rbind", combn(d$INSTITUTION, 2, simplify = FALSE)))
}))
```

This splits the original data by group, then performs an operation within each group. That operation is, if there is more than one row in the group, take all pairwise combinations of members of the group (removing duplicates, though there shouldn't be any). Finally, it binds all the results into a single matrix.

To restrict the dataset to edges that appear more than ten times, first, create an "edge ID", then tabulate the edge IDs and remove all that have 10 or fewer appearances.

```
edgeID <- do.call(paste, as.data.frame(out))
tab <- table(edgeID)
out <- out[edgeID %in% names(tab)[tab > 10],,drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I learned a lot from this solution in terms of manipulating data in base R. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code with `split` + `make_full_graph` + `get.data.frame`

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    with(df, split(INSTITUTION, GROUP)),
    function(v) {
      make_full_graph(length(v)) %>%
        set_vertex_attr(name = "name", value = v) %>%
        get.data.frame()
    }
  )
)
```

which gives

```
                from          to
Group1   University1 University1
Group2.1 University3 University4
Group2.2 University3 University1
Group2.3 University4 University1
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ThomasIsCoding! This answer is great because it maintains the unique group codes, so it is easy to verify that I am getting the kind of edgelist I want.